# Getting JSON from Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I am using the following function for converting the form code to JSON, it is pretty much and works awesome

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
        {
           var o = {};
           var a = this.serializeArray();
           $.each(a, function() {
               if (o[this.name]) {
                   if (!o[this.name].push) {
                       o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                   }
                   o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
               } else {
                   o[this.name] = this.value || '';
               }
           });
           return o;
        };
```

Now it gives me results as: [if form fields have different names] and form field names as `direction1,direction2,direction3`

```
{direction1: "abc", direction2: "xyz", direction3: "def"}
```

if they have same name say `address` of all form fields : it combines them as:

```
Object {address: Array[3]} address: Array[3] 0: "dfddf" 1: "dfdfdf" 2: "fewwewe"length: 3
```

which is correct

I am trying to get the results as:

```
{"address": "abc"}, 
{"address": "xyz"}, 
{"address": "def"}
```

how can i make this change

Comment: So you want to remove the number at the end of the input name? Your function always returns an object, the results you're trying to get looks like an array.

Comment: If you want to handle those with a common name differently, I'd start by selecting them separately with getElementsByName() (or library equivalent) or otherwise handle them separately if you want to handle all elements in one loop.

Comment: so what should my way of doing it, if needed through loop, please guide

Comment: Well, if in one loop. you do a conditional that runs if this.name=="address".  In that loop, you simply do o.push({this.name:this.value}) -- which would give you a set of objects in your array which each contain one element with that identical "address" key, as you show above. And you'd do what you have above (more or less) in the else.  Hang on, I'll correct what I say her and post an actual answer.  Sorry -- just sort of got your code.

Comment: user1167442 (great name, very unique.  literally) has a good point, below.

Comment: @Matt, Thanks but can you write proper code, because what i had written above s not a function written by me, i am very much noob in javascript, jquery, regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sleep deprived, so there's def a better way to do this, but this seems to do what you want, if I understand. this will make every array an array of objs in the form of `{"objkey": valAtIndex }`. So in this case, `Object {address: Array[3]} address: Array[3] 0: "dfddf" 1: "dfdfdf" 2: "fewwewe"length: 3` would become:

```
{"address":[
  {"address": "dfddf"}, 
  {"address": "dfdfdf"}, 
  {"address": "fewwewe"}
]}
```

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/44254b6f157cfbbfebd2f73cbe1a4526?editors=101)

html

```
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="text" name='address' value='123' />
  <input type="text" name='address' value='456' />
</form>
```

js

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name]) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   return o;
};
$(function() {
  var t = $('#form').serializeObject();
  Object.keys(t).forEach(function(key) {
    if (t[key].constructor === Array) {
      t[key].forEach(function(a, i) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[key] = a;
        t[key][i] = obj;
      });
    }
  });
  var myAddresses = t["address"];

  console.log(JSON.stringify(myAddresses, null, 4));
});
```

Edit: to access them, use `t["address"]` as above. Looking at the console after running the code, you'd see:

```
[
    { "address": "123" },
    { "address": "456" }
]
```

edit: removed confusing "result" section.

Comment: awesome, one issue: it gives me result as `{"address": [     {"address": "Halifax, NS, Canada"},{"address": "Toronto, ON, Canada"},{"address": "Winnipeg, MB, Canada"}]}` which is perfect as what it should produce according to your code

Comment: i am checking it as: `{"addresses": [     {"address": "Halifax, NS, Canada"},{"address": "Toronto, ON, Canada"},{"address": "Winnipeg, MB, Canada"}]}` notice the `es` at the start to differentiate it

Comment: yeah, pluralization is an interesting thought, for sure. Not convinced it's all that practical granting the use case. Personally, I'd just go with `t["address"]` to access the 'address' objs.

Comment: so did u made any change how i fix this

Comment: that's how you'd access your objects in the array: t['address'] == `[{"address": "Halifax, NS, Canada"},{"address": "Toronto, ON, Canada"},{"address": "Winnipeg, MB, Canada"}];`

Comment: idk what your specific use case is, but it'd be done as it is normally, only with the `t["address"]` rather than only `t`. "t" is also a horrible var name; sorry for that. :/

Comment: so u mean like this: `{t["addresses"]: [t]}`

Comment: No, dude. So, t is our car, right? We don't want to put it in Ann object as the key. and it's not addresses, it's address. You **access** the array through the the variable **t**, which is an object with the property address, and the outer **address** is the key to an inner array of objects who also have an address property. Check the edit.

Comment: glad i can help, man. sorry for the crazy typos above; i was on mobile. lol. so bad.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just extending and object rather than creating an array like you want.
Whether JSON-Like Object or Array is what you want, you still need to have a key that corresponds to each Object if you want them as separate objects.  So, instead of:

```
  o[this.name]=this.value
```

You need

```
    var obj={};
    obj[this.name]=this.value;
```

Then:

```
    o.push(obj);
```

Or:

```
    o[a key of your definition]=obj;
```

That will then give you seperate objects  inside of `o` like you want.

Comment: can you rewrite the function, its getting confused and i am getting lost while changing...

Comment: I can't quite get my head around what you're going after, and I don't have the time to figure it, but 1.  I think you're making this harder than it needs to be, and 2.  If you need an array of object or a pseudo-array Object of objects, you need to add the object to the parent rather adding a key to the parent.  If you add a key to a parent, that will extend the parent object with a new value rather than extending the parent object with a new object.